# Surjective differentiable function from R to R²

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

How can I prove there is no function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}²$ of class $C¹$ that is surjective?
This is an exercise from Analysis on Manifolds, from Munkres.

The exercise gives a hint that is: $f(\mathbb{R})$ does not contain an open subset from $\mathbb{R}²$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $f'$ is continuous, $|f'(x)|$ is continuous too, and is bounded on each closed interval $[a,b]$. So $f$ has finite curve length on every such interval.

Therefore $f([0,1])$ can be covered by finitely many disks of total Lebesgue measure at most $1$. And $f([1,2])$ can be covered by disks of total measure at most $1/2$. And so forth -- if we cover every $f([n,n+1])$ with disks of total measure at most $2^{-|n|}$ we get all of $f(\mathbb R)$ covered by an open set of measure at most $3$.

Thus the Lebesgue measure of $f(\mathbb R)$ is $\le 3$ -- in particular it is finite, so $f(\mathbb R)$ can't be all of $\mathbb R^2$.

---

(In fact what essentially this argument proves is that the image of a $\mathcal C^1$ function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ where $m>n$ always has zero measure).